# Send Zebra Feed Command

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

1. How do i send a feed command to a zebra ze500 printer - I want to
   emulate pressing the feed button on the front of the unit.
2. You can set the Media Feed function to Feed and upon closing the door or on
   bootup it will feed 12 labels. How do i send a command to do this
   exact sequence ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to print something, but it can be a space.

^xa^aa^fd ^fs^xz

Comment: and what about question 2?

Comment: Are you trying to make it feed 12 labels on boot up? Trying to make it feed on boot up. Or fix an issue where it is feeding 12 labels on boot up?

Answer (score 0):

The question number2: I am not sure but I think you are trying to explain the label calibration. For this purpose send the ~JC command to the printer